# BadMethodCallException using children_comments()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm currently attempting to make comment replies (Threaded-ish)
I keep getting an error saying:

> BadMethodCallException Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::children_comments()

Here's my Method:

```
public function commentsReply(Requests\CreateCommentsRequest $request, $comment)
{
$comments = Comments::whereId($comment)->first();

    $comment = new ChildrenComment(Request::all());
    $comment->pubslished_at = Carbon::now();
    $comment->user()->associate(Auth::user());
    $comment->children_comments()->associate($comments);
    $comment->save();

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

Here's my model:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class ChildrenComment extends Model {
protected $fillable = [
        'id',
        'user_id',
        'post_id',
        'parent_id',
        'comment'
    ];

    public function setPublishedAtAttribute($date)
    {
        $this->attributes['pubslished_at'] = Carbon::parse($date);
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Comments');
    }

}
```

And if necessary here is my migration schema:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('children_comments', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned();
        $table->text('comment');
        $table->string('fileToUpload')->default("uploads/images/comments/NFF4D00-0.png");
        $table->timestamps();;
        $table->foreign('user_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('users')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('post_id')
                ->references('id')
                    ->on('posts')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('parent_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('comments')
                    ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `associate` method in a wrong way. The method `children_comments()` that you are calling here doesn't exists anywhere:

```
$comment->children_comments()->associate($comments);
```

To associate a `Comments` to a `ChildrenComment` you should do like this:

```
$comment->comments()->associate($comments);
```

A final note: i find the way you're naming your variables very confusing(expecially because you are using a plural form for a variable with a single value) . I would do like this:

```
//is't only one comment so 'comment' not 'comments'
$comment = Comments::whereId($comment)->first();

//$childComment is another object, so give it another name
$childComment = new ChildrenComment(Request::all());
$childComment->pubslished_at = Carbon::now();
$childComment->user()->associate(Auth::user());

//this statement represent a relation with one element, so name it 'comment()', not 'comments()'
$childComment->comment()->associate( $comment );
$childComment->save();
```

i think that this will make it a lot more readable

Comment: I get another error saying:

`Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::associate() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, null given, called in {PATH}\PostsController.php on line 172 and defined`

Comment: check that the variable `$comments` is defined after you get it. you can check this way: `dd($comments)`